# Tasksel cinnamon install stuck at 81%

Tags: cinnamon, headless, tasksel

Not sure what to do as my Ubuntu headless server is now stuck on a purple terminal gui.

I've tried to use tasksel to install cinnamon-desktop. It seems it's now stuck on 81% which is displayed as "preparing to configure network-manager"

I don't know what to do from here.

Any help at this point would be fantastic.

thanks all.

Comment: You've not told us what base OS/release you're using... we could only guess.